# How to solve eval error in RMarkdown referred to dimension

Tags: r, r-markdown, eval

I am struggling with this rendering oin RMarkdown

````
---
title: "trial"
author: "X"
date: "X"
output:
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '2'
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    theme: journal
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_crop: no
    fig_height: 4
    fig_width: 7
    highlight: haddock
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{float}
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/graphics-', 
                 cache.path='cache/graphics-', 
                 fig.align='center',
                 external=TRUE,
                 echo=TRUE,
                 warning=FALSE,
                 fig.pos='H', ft.tabcolsep=0, ft.latex.float = "none"
                )
    ---
    
`{r echo=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}
    
dat_na = data.frame(v1 =ifelse(ttINT_1$HMM$tt$incl == "-", NA, ttINT_1$HMM$tt$incl),
                    v2 = ifelse(ttINT_1$IMM$tt$incl == "-",NA, ttINT_1$IMM$tt$incl), 
                    v3 = ifelse(ttINT_1$LMM$tt$incl == "-",NA, ttINT_1$LMM$tt$incl)
)
````

It turns this error:

[image]

I cannot understand what it refers to. It works isolating the code as a chunk

Answer (score 1):

Your yaml should be between `---` and your chunks are not rightly created using the ` sign like this:

````
---
title: "trial"
author: "X"
date: "X"
output:
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '2'
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    theme: journal
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_crop: no
    fig_height: 4
    fig_width: 7
    highlight: haddock
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{float}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/graphics-', 
                 cache.path='cache/graphics-', 
                 fig.align='center',
                 external=TRUE,
                 echo=TRUE,
                 warning=FALSE,
                 fig.pos='H', ft.tabcolsep=0, ft.latex.float = "none"
                )
```

```{r echo=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}
    
dat_na = data.frame(v1 =ifelse(ttINT_1$HMM$tt$incl == "-", NA, ttINT_1$HMM$tt$incl),
                    v2 = ifelse(ttINT_1$IMM$tt$incl == "-",NA, ttINT_1$IMM$tt$incl), 
                    v3 = ifelse(ttINT_1$LMM$tt$incl == "-",NA, ttINT_1$LMM$tt$incl))
```
````

Comment: Could you please show this better? It is not that clear to me. If you mean to put the code like this `---{r echo=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}`, I have already made a trial with another .Rmd doc to work as I did, but it gave me problem. It is something in that dataframe that I could not understand

Comment: Hi @alias, your YAML is your first part which is between the --- signs like for your author and date etc. In RMarkdown you can use chunks which is defined between the ``` sign where you can add your code. They were not complete in your code. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Probably it would be an error in how I paste the code. But the message refers to a dataset in that chuck that has different row length

Comment: I have updated the yaml. It was an error on my end

Comment: I meant that I have made the update in the reprex here (it is exactly as I have on my RMarkdown). My problem is not solved yet

Comment: Hi @alias, Did you try running my code with the created chunks?

Comment: Hi. It does not work. That is only the chuck which gives me some troubles that in my script is on 312 line. I do not think it will depend on that, but it will be more about how the dataset it is built, according to I can understand from that message